# Auto-play Open Graph Protocol Videos in Facebook Mobile News Feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-opengraph

Has anyone been able to figure out the open graph tags to get a video to auto-play like Facebook-native uploaded videos do?

I've been able to successfully link a video to my URL in the share preview/url debugger using og:video tags but it doesn't play automatically on mobile like if I upload it directly as a shared video.

These are the open graph tags I have now:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id"             content="_______" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="article:publisher"     content="https://www.facebook.com/______" />
<meta property="og:site_name"          content="_______" />
<meta property="og:url"                content="https://_______.com/_______/_______" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="_______" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="_______" />

<meta property="og:image"              content="https://_______.com/images/opengraph.png" />
<meta property="og:video"              content="http://_______.com/videos/_______.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url"   content="https://_______.com/videos/_______.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:type"         content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width"        content="480" />
<meta property="og:video:height"       content="320" />
```

My videos show up like this when I share them on Facebook:

[image: Video shared through OGP]

I'd like them to show up like this (note: this is auto-playing when I scroll through my news feed which happens when you upload a video directly through Facebook):

[image: Video shared on Facebook]